# Queues in Ocaml - enq

Tags: algorithm, ocaml

I can't seem to get my code working enq. How am I supposed to declare the queue datattype as well?

```
let enq (q, x) =
  match q with
    queue ([], b) -> queue([], x::b)
  | queue (f, []) -> queue(f, [x])
  | queue (f, b)  -> queue(f, x::b);;
```

Comment: what do you want to do ? What is your function supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between the name of the type and the constructor names used to make elements of the type. For your code, the type name could be `queue` (type names begin with lower case) and you could have just a single constructor named `Queue` (constructors begin with upper case).

The type declaration would look like this then:

```
type 'a queue = Queue of 'a list * 'a list
```

Note that this type is parameterized by the type of the elements of the queue (denoted as `'a` in the declaration).

In your code, the pattern matches should be against the constructor `Queue`, not against the type name `queue`.

I would also say as a side comment that all the cases in your code look the same to me. I suspect there might be just one case.